# Finding Not null on multiple columns using COALESCE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, notnull

I have a query to find not null on 2 columns on a table which is a view , hence it is taking a lot of time for execution.
The query is : Query1

```
SELECT [Table1].M, [[Table1]].B, [Table1].P
FROM [Table1]
WHERE ((([[Table1]].B) Is Not Null) AND (([[Table1]].P) Is Not Null));
```

Does the below query does the same function as Query1 with faster execution time ?

```
SELECT [Table1].M, [[Table1]].B, [Table1].P
FROM [Table1]
WHERE COALESCE (([[Table1]].B),([[Table1]].P)) Is Not Null
```

Any help would be of great help and thanks in advance.

The view query

```
select dbo.TABLE1.[COL1]
    , dbo.TABLE1.[COL2]
    , RIGHT(dbo.TABLE1.M, 12) as M
    , dbo.TABLE2.[MD]
    , dbo.TABLE1.[COL3]
    , dbo.TABLE1.[COL4]
    , dbo.TABLE3.COL1
    , dbo.TABLE3.[COL2]
    , dbo.TABLE3.[COL3]
    , dbo.TABLE4.[COL1]
    , dbo.TABLE5.[COL1]
    , dbo.TABLE6.[COL1]
    , dbo.TABLE7.[COL1] as [BA]
    , dbo.TABLE8.[COL1]
    , dbo.TABLE3.[COL4]
    , dbo.TABLE3.[COL5]
    , dbo.TABLE3.[COL6]
from dbo.TABLE1
left outer join dbo.TABLE2
    on dbo.TABLE1.M = dbo.TABLE2.M
left outer join dbo.TABLE3
    on dbo.TABLE1.M = dbo.TABLE3.M
left outer join dbo.TABLE5
    on dbo.TABLE3.[OBJ_NR] = dbo.TABLE5.OBJ
left outer join dbo.TABLE6
    on dbo.TABLE3.[OBJ_NR] = dbo.TABLE6.OBJ
left outer join dbo.TABLE7
    on dbo.TABLE3.[OBJ_NR] = dbo.TABLE7.OBJ
left outer join dbo.TABLE4
    on dbo.TABLE3.[OBJ_NR] = dbo.TABLE4.OBJ
left outer join dbo.TABLE8
    on dbo.TABLE3.[OBJ_NR] = dbo.TABLE8.OBJ
where (
        (
            dbo.TABLE1.[COL1] not in (
                'XX'
                , 'YY'
                )
            )
        and (dbo.TABLE1.COL5 = 'x')
        )
```

Comment: It's probably spending half the time working out all those parentheses. ;)

Comment: More seriously, have you tried creating test data and seeing if your premise is correct or not? Run it a few thousand times and check the output and execution times, etc.

Comment: I'm an amateur learning my tricks through the forums like this. It would be of great help if I get some ideas how to approach situations like this. Thanks

Comment: Pay more attention to my second comment than my first (although the first *is* a hint towards making it a bit more readable and thus maintainable). Create two loops - one for each - and run each version, see which is faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, both queries aren't equivalent.

The `WHERE` clause in the second one is equivalent to

```
WHERE [[Table1]].B Is Not Null OR [[Table1]].P Is Not Null
```

`COALESCE` will evaluate the first parameter and return it if not null. Otherwise, it will return the second one if not null, and so on, until reaching the last parameter, which will be returned whatever its value. So `COALESCE(...) IS NOT NULL` needs only one not null value to return true, not all.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me on that. Is there a way if I could use a function for finding not nulls on multiple columns.

Comment: I don't think so. Anyway, I doubt the `NOT NULL` tests are the bottleneck here. What do your indexes look like ? How big is your table ?

Comment: My table is around 3 million record which is a view. I dont have a schema , so should I include WITH SCHEMABINDING fro views.

Comment: I don't think so, but I don't know really this option. My bet is an index issue.

Comment: The view is formed from multiple left n right joins. So I can't index them I believe. I get an error when I do with Schemabinding for indexing reasons. Cannot create index on view "xxx" because it uses a LEFT, RIGHT, or FULL OUTER join, and no OUTER joins are allowed in indexed views. Consider using an INNER join instead.

Comment: If you're view is based on a particularly complex query, it's not surprising that it takes some time to execute, especially with outer joins.

Comment: I did some reverse engineering and added some indexes on certain fields. I reran the query and it took just 1.32 mins to return 3 million records :).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this out on a table in my development DB. Here are the results:

with only PK index: 2 minutes for 4 million selected records out of 8 million table

with index on 3 selected columns (none of them PK) 1.8 seconds.

You might need to do some testing to get the right indexes for your setup but here is the sample of what i changed:

```
select [col1]
    , [col2]
    , [col3]
from [dbo].[tbl]
where col2 is not null
    and col3 is not null

create nonclustered index [idx_test] on [dbo].[tbl] (
    [col2] asc
    , [col3] asc
    ) INCLUDE ([col1])
```

Comment: My table is a view and I'm unable to create joins on them due to having joins in them. I get an error as " Cannot create index on view "xxx" because it uses a LEFT, RIGHT, or FULL OUTER join, and no OUTER joins are allowed in indexed views. Consider using an INNER join instead "

Comment: @Lewan a view isnt a table. a view views tables. make the index on the tables your view is viewing.

Comment: I have indexes on pirmary keys on most tables the view uses. I was just thinking if I could have index views which I can't in my case since my view involves outer joins. I don't want to rewrite several queries to suit this.

Comment: @Lewan Can you post a anonymized version of the view definition?

Comment: I'm unable to post the code here. I have included the query in the question. Please check. Thanks

Comment: @Lewan Rather than just having indexes on your primary keys, look at the queries you're running and tailor them accordingly; also investigate which field(s) may be best for a clustered index as (IME) that's rarely the primary key.

Comment: @AdrianWragg I did some reverse engineering and added some indexes on certain fields. I reran the query and it took just 1.32 mins to return 3 million records :). Thanks for idea I appreciate it.